# how to get unique count and dynamically generate text

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'User':['101','101','102','102','102','101','102','103','103','103','101'],
    'Product':['x','xy','y','z','z','x','y','z','x','y',''],
    'Country':['India','India','India','Brazil','India','UK','UK','Brazil','India','UK','USA']})
```

[image: df]

and i need to get country wise unique product and users like this below

[image: df2]

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, use `nunique` and `agg`

```
df.groupby('Country').nunique()[['User', 'Product']].agg(lambda f: "{} users and {} products".format(f['User'], f['Product']), 1)

Country
Brazil    2 users and 1 products
India     3 users and 4 products
UK        3 users and 2 products
dtype: object
```

If you want to customize your repr, you can build a more detailed function, for example:

```
def repr_(f):
    users = "{} user(s)".format(f['User']) if f['User'] else ''
    products = "{} product(s)".format(f['Product']) if f['Product'] else ''
    z = [str_ for str_ in (users, products) if str_]
    return " and ".join(z)
```

And using `.agg(repr_, 1)`, which works if there is only one user, only one product or many of both.

```
Country
Brazil    2 user(s) and 1 product(s)
India     3 user(s) and 4 product(s)
UK        3 user(s) and 2 product(s)
USA                        1 user(s)
dtype: object
```

---

To state which users/products,

```
def repr_(s):
    u, p = s['User'], s['Product']
    us, pr = ("{} user(s) ({})".format(len(u), ', '.join(u)) if len(u) else '',\
             "{} product(s) ({})".format(len(p), ', '.join(p)) if len(p) else '')
    z = [str_ for str_ in [us, pr] if str_]
    return " and ".join(z)

df.groupby('Country').agg(lambda s: set([x for x in s if x])).agg(repr_,1)

Country
Brazil            2 user(s) (102, 103) and 1 product(s) (z)
India     3 user(s) (101, 102, 103) and 4 product(s) (z,...
UK        3 user(s) (101, 102, 103) and 2 product(s) (y, x)
USA                                         1 user(s) (101)
dtype: object
```

Comment: USA country is missing here..can we write if conditions to generate that text also text?

Comment: @KumarAK there is no USA in your input code ;} just in your images

Comment: @user3483203 he just edited it to add it haha. Kumar, thats simple, I'll edit in 1 min

Comment: @KumarAK of course you can add `if` statements to make it `product` or `products` depending on if `1` or `> 1`, but I guess you can pick up from there ;)

Comment: Thanks..def repr_(f):
    country = "{} have".format(f['Country']) if f['Country'] else ''
    users = "{} user(s)".format(f['User']) if f['User'] else ''
    products = "{} product(s)".format(f['Product']) if f['Product'] else ''
    z = [str_ for str_ in (country,users, products) if str_]
    return " and ".join(z)                                                                                                                                             df.groupby('Country').nunique()[['User', 'Product']].reset_index().agg(repr_, 1)

Comment: how to remove and in the text

Comment: @KumarAK `and` will only be added when you have *both* users and products greater than 0 (just like in your expected output you posted..)

Comment: how to show the product and users list also? example text for Brazil : " Brazil have 2 users (s) (102 and 103) and 1 product(s) (z) "

Comment: Personally I think this is well answer all f-string like question , he just need to put more effort on it .